# mysql_num_rows from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking to count the amount of fields in 5 tables and display a result. I currently do this for a single table

```
    $variable = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table1"));
```

What is the most efficient way to include and count all `id` from `table2`, `table3`, `table4` and `table5`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` to combine the `SELECT` queries on all the tables to get the total number of IDs from all the tables. Use `UNION` instead to get total number of `distinct` IDs from all the tables.

```
$variable = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("
    "SELECT id FROM table1 " .
    "UNION ALL " .
    "SELECT id FROM table2 " .
    "UNION ALL " .
    "SELECT id FROM table3 " .
    "UNION ALL " .
    "SELECT id FROM table4 " .
    "UNION ALL " .
    "SELECT id FROM table5"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't get all rows from your DB, just get the num of id's. Let MySQL count instead of PHP.

```
    $variable1 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table1");
    $variable2 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table2");
    $variable3 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table3");
    $variable4 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table4");
    $variable5 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table5");

    $variable = $variable1 + $variable2 + $variable3 + $variable4 +$variable5;
```

Don't make UNION or JOIN neither, it's a heavywight job if you just need the count.

Comment: See my response... computation is more efficiently done, serverside, in SQL than PHP

Comment: Well you don't have a where clause so I am not quite sure if it also does a join here but normally even if you don't use the word using multiple tables is also a join. That is the reason I did all seperately.

Comment: the OP merely wanted a count of all the rows in 5 tables, from my understanding. No where clause is needed for this solution and my point still stands, that SQL is much faster at this computation than PHP

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT count(t1.id)+count(t2.id)+count(t3.id)+count(t4.id)+count(t5.id) from table1 as t1, table2 as t2, table3 as t3, table4 as t4, table5 as t5`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table2
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

try union syntax like this:

```
$variable = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM(
  SELECT id FROM table1
  UNION
  SELECT id FROM table2
  UNION
  SELECT id FROM table3
  UNION
  SELECT id FROM table4
  UNION
  SELECT id FROM table5
)unionNum
"));
```

Finish, good luck

Answer (score 0):

First Method:

```
$query = mysql_query("
    select * from(
        SELECT id FROM table1
        union
        SELECT id FROM table2
        union
        SELECT id FROM table3
        union
        SELECT id FROM table4
    )
");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    //some operations
}
$variable = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Second Method:

```
$query = mysql_query("
    select count(*) cnt from(
        SELECT id FROM table1
        union
        SELECT id FROM table2
        union
        SELECT id FROM table3
        union
        SELECT id FROM table4
    )
");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $variable = $query['cnt'];
}
```